# change Pandas Row background colour and Font Colors based on 2 different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have a code to change the cell background colour if the `Rising` is False. I want to change the **Cell** Colour to Green if the value in the `Index` is `Nifty 50`.

So If any rows is from `Nifty 50` but `Rising` is False, then the `Nifty 50` cell should be in Green background of that Only cell and all of the other cells should be in Red.

This is what I want the Dataframe to look like: Whole Row is Red if
`Rising` is `False or 0`.  Color of `Index` is changed based on whether it is from `Nifty-50/100/200`

[image]

And the code for changing color is as follows:

```
def highlight_falling(s, column:str):
        '''
        Highlight The rows where average is falling
        args:
            s: Series
            column: Column name(s)
        '''
        is_max = pd.Series(data=False, index=s.index)
        is_max[column] = s.loc[column] == True
        return ['' if is_max.any() else 'background-color: #f7a8a8' for v in is_max]

picked.style.apply(highlight_falling, column=['Rising'], axis=1) # picked is the DF
```

Here I want to give the Index of 50,100,200,500 cell as `[Green,Blue,Magenta. White]` (just tan example)

Comment: Can you also include some code that can be run to build a representation of `picked`? It also might help make things more clear if you mocked up what colors should go where in excel or something to _show_ what the output should look like.

Comment: @HenryEcker I have updated the Screenshot and added the logic of how it should be done above the image. I just want to know the function name and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to associate the values in the column with the new color styles. We will then apply the `Index` column styles after the row styles so as to override the previously placed red colour:

```
def highlight_falling(f: pd.DataFrame, column: str):
    # Create an Empty DataFrame
    f_styles = pd.DataFrame('', index=f.index, columns=f.columns)
    # Apply Styles based on column. (Set red where not Truthy)
    f_styles.loc[~(f[column].astype(bool)), :] = 'background-color: #f7a8a8'
    return f_styles


def highlight_nifty(s: pd.Series):
    return 'background-color: ' + s.map({
        'Nifty 50': 'green',
        'Nifty 100': 'blue',
        'Nifty 200': '#888888'
    })  # Map to colour codes


# Save Styler To Re-use (can also Chain)
styler = picked.style
# Apply Row Colour (Do not pass column as List[str] use str!!)
styler.apply(highlight_falling, column='Rising', axis=None)
# Apply Index Column Colours
styler.apply(highlight_nifty, subset='Index')
```

[image: styled table]

---

The mapping dictionary could also be created with `dict` and `zip` if wanted to specify a list of colors can use [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get all unique values from the Index column, then [`natsorted`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) can be used to order them (safe alphanumeric ordering):

```
from natsort import natsorted
from typing import List


def highlight_falling(f: pd.DataFrame, column: str):
    # Create an Empty DataFrame
    f_styles = pd.DataFrame('', index=f.index, columns=f.columns)
    # Apply Styles based on column. (Set red where not Truthy)
    f_styles.loc[~(f[column].astype(bool)), :] = 'background-color: #f7a8a8'
    return f_styles



def highlight_nifty(s: pd.Series, colours: List[str]):
    return 'background-color: ' + s.map(
        # Build Colour Map Dynamically based on unique values from column
        dict(zip(natsorted(s.unique()), colours))
    )  # Map to colour codes


# Save Styler To Re-use (can also Chain)
styler = picked.style
# Apply Row Colour (Do not pass column as List[str] use str!!)
styler.apply(highlight_falling, column='Rising', axis=None)
# Apply Index Column Colours
styler.apply(highlight_nifty, subset='Index',
             colours=['green', 'blue', '#888888'])
```

[image: styled table]